# Python multiprocessing apply_async: what am I missing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand how the apply_async function of the multiprocessing library is working but I keep banging my head against the wall. What did I missed?

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import time
    import threading

    def test():
        time.sleep(15)
        print "test"

    def test_launcher():
        pool = Pool(processes=1)
        result = pool.apply_async(test)

    def printit():
      threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
      print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "Before"
        test_launcher()
        print "After"

        printit()
```

I don't want to wait for the return of test(), I want to continue and get the printing from test() when it had finish.

Shouldn't it be printing "test" after 2 or 3 printing of time?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the main process to wait for the child processes, then add:

```
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

After the last print statement. Otherwise the main process will terminate before the child process finishes

Comment: I've added more code to demonstrate that test() is going to be running in a never ending python script. I just want to print "test" when test() is ready to do it. I don't want to wait for it.